# Typings for not main file

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, typescript-typings, package.json

I have a `package.json` like a

```
{
    "name": "some-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "typings": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

And in typescript i can use this package like a

```
import someProject from "some-project";
```

But I have another file `helpers.js`
And I want use this like a

```
import someProject from "some-project/helpers";
```

How i can create typing for this file?
He has nothing to do with `index.js` 
Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a little bit different approach to separate your typings into logical "blocks".

In your index.ts:

```
export * from './main';

import * as helpers from './helpers';
export {helpers};
```

Then you can use your helpers functionality in a manner similar to what you asked for:

```
import * as sp from 'some-project'
sp.doSomething();
sp.helpers.doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `index.ts` (from which `index.d.ts` is generated) is the entry point which exports all symbol of the library/package. In your case, there are many different isolated modules in one package, and there is not a facade to exports all of these isolated module from one place

Alter **tsconfig** is the ultimate solution. By default `excludes` in `tsconfig` has `node_modules`, which means your definitions other than `index.d.ts` will not be included in compilation. You can change this by explicitly defined `includes` to include all `.ts`, `.d.ts`, `.tsx` from particular directories.

```
"include": [
  "node_modules/yourPackage/**/*",
  "yourWorkingDirectory/**/*"
]
```

`"yourWorkingDirectory/**/*"` also need to be added to the array since you're defining `includes` explicitly.

Comment: More information here about `includes` and `excludes`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html